# Complex query to find the latest DocRevision AND the last DocRevi sent to Customer

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a document management system, but I seem to be stuck.

The database contains all documentnumbers (unique) and all their revisions (A-B-C-etc). When a document is sent to the client, I use a transmittal (Document 1234, Revision B was sent with Transmittal 6 to Client XYZ).

Now the team wishes an overview (table), where they can see for each document the latest revision AND which was the last revision, sent to Client XYZ. Something like this:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Documents  || Latest Revision || Last sent Revision                                  |
    |            || revision        || revision   | transmittalnr   | sent To     | Reason |
    -------------||-----------------||- ---------------------------------------------------
    |            ||                 ||            |                 |             |        |
    | [docnrlab] || [revision]      || [revision] | [transmittalnr] | [userto_id] | [rsn]  |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been trying to achieve it with one query, but since I'm not an expert I don't seem to get it done. What I got (by trial-and-error, which is probably not the best way to build complex queries)

```
    /* all docs with al their revis */
    SELECT * , revisiondate, docrevisions.id
    FROM docrevisions
    ORDER BY doc_id



    /* for each doc: give the latest revi, which has a transmittal */
    SELECT * , MAX( revisiondate ), docrevisions.id AS revi_id, transmittals2revisions . *
    FROM docrevisions
    LEFT JOIN transmittals2revisions ON docrevisions.id = transmittals2revisions.revisions_id
    LEFT JOIN transmittals ON transmittals2revisions.transmittal_id = transmittals.id
    WHERE transmittals.id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY doc_id



    /* testing */
    SELECT docrevisions.id AS sent, docrevisions.id AS unsent, documents.docnrlab
    FROM docrevisions
    INNER JOIN transmittals2revisions AS t2revi1 ON sent = t2revi1.revisions_id
    INNER JOIN transmittals2revisions AS t2revi2 ON unsent = t2revi2.revisions_id
    INNER JOIN documents ON docrevisions.doc_id = documents.id
    WHERE t2revi1.revisions_id IS NOT NULL
    AND t2revi2.revisions_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY doc_id
    ORDER BY docrevisions.doc_id ASC
```

In an other query I use aliasses, which I thought would be helpful with my problem, but I don't know how to find the right one:

```
    $sql = "SELECT trm.*, userfrom.lastname AS UserFrom, userto.lastname AS UserTo 
            FROM transmittals AS trm 
            LEFT JOIN users AS userfrom ON userfrom.id = trm.userfrom_id
            LEFT JOIN users AS userto ON userto.id = trm.userto_id";
```

Below is the structure of the datatables involved

```
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `docguard` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
    USE `docguard` ;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `docguard`.`documents`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docguard`.`documents` (
      `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `docnrsupplier` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docnrlab` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docnrclient` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `title1` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `title2` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `title3` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `title4` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docsize_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docstate_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docformat_editable_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docformat_noneditable_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
      `file_editable` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `file_noneditable` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `doccat_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docphase_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `doctype_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `company_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `docrevisions_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
      INDEX `fk_documents_docrevisions_idx` (`docrevisions_id` ASC) )
    ENGINE = MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 778
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `docguard`.`docrevisions`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docguard`.`docrevisions` (
      `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `doc_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
      `revision` TEXT NOT NULL ,
      `revisiondate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `user_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `transmittals2revisions_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
      INDEX `fk_docrevisions_transmittals2revisions1_idx` (`transmittals2revisions_id` ASC) )
    ENGINE = MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 1199
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `docguard`.`transmittals2revisions`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docguard`.`transmittals2revisions` (
      `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `transmittal_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
      `revisions_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `quantity` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
      `rsn` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
    ENGINE = MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 607
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `docguard`.`transmittals`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docguard`.`transmittals` (
      `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `transmittalnr` TEXT NOT NULL ,
      `userfrom_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `userto_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `shippingtimestamp` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `replybeforetimestamp` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `note` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
      `tempname` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
      `transmittals2revisions_id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
      INDEX `fk_transmittals_transmittals2revisions1_idx` (`transmittals2revisions_id` ASC) )
    ENGINE = MyISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 52
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

My apologies for the long post, but I was hoping someone might be able to help me out or point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Konstantin Kiselev has pointed me to the right solution, so a big Thank you to him.
I'll write here how I solved my problem with his proposals:

1. To find revision with latest date among all chosen document's revisions - changed from the above, because I need the actual revision (A-B-C-etc) too:

   ```
   SELECT d.docnrlab, dr.*
   FROM documents d, docrevisions AS dr
   INNER JOIN 
   (
       SELECT dr.id, dr.doc_id, MAX( revisiondate ) AS revisiondate
       FROM docrevisions AS dr
       GROUP BY doc_id
   ) 
   AS CurrentRevision 
       ON CurrentRevision.doc_id = dr.doc_id
       AND CurrentRevision.revisiondate = dr.revisiondate
   WHERE d.id = dr.doc_id
   ```
2. To find revision with latest date among all chosen document's revisions which was transmitted to user XYZ - I had not mentioned that it is possible that a document has not been sent at all.

   ```
   SELECT dr.id, dr.doc_id, dr.revision , MAX( revisiondate ), 
       tr.transmittalnr, tr.userto_id,
       t2r.rsn,
       MAX(tr.shippingtimestamp)
   FROM docrevisions dr
   LEFT JOIN transmittals2revisions AS t2r ON dr.id = t2r.revisions_id
   LEFT JOIN transmittals AS tr ON t2r.transmittal_id = tr.id
   /*WHERE tr.id IS NOT NULL*/
   GROUP BY doc_id
   ```

/* All together now */

```
SELECT d.id doc_id, 
    d.docnrlab doc_nr_lab,
    rl.id last_revision_id, 
    rl.revision last_revision,
    rlt.id last_trans_revision_id, 
    rlt.revision last_trans_revision,
    rlt.transmittalnr,
    rlt.userto_id,
    rlt.rsn
FROM documents d,
    (
        SELECT d.docnrlab, dr.*
        FROM documents d, docrevisions AS dr
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT dr.id, dr.doc_id, MAX( revisiondate ) AS revisiondate
            FROM docrevisions AS dr
            GROUP BY doc_id
        ) 
        AS CurrentRevision 
            ON CurrentRevision.doc_id = dr.doc_id
            AND CurrentRevision.revisiondate = dr.revisiondate
        WHERE d.id = dr.doc_id
    ) rl,
    (
        SELECT dr.id, dr.doc_id, dr.revision , MAX( revisiondate ), 
            tr.transmittalnr, tr.userto_id,
            t2r.rsn,
            MAX(tr.shippingtimestamp)
        FROM docrevisions dr
        LEFT JOIN transmittals2revisions AS t2r ON dr.id = t2r.revisions_id
        LEFT JOIN transmittals AS tr ON t2r.transmittal_id = tr.id
        /*WHERE tr.id IS NOT NULL*/
        GROUP BY doc_id
    ) rlt
WHERE d.id = rl.doc_id 
    AND d.id = rlt.doc_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you need perform two analytical queries:

1. To find revision with latest date among all chosen document's revisions:

   ```
   SELECT dr.doc_id, dr.id, MAX(dr.revisiondate)
     FROM docrevisions dr
     GROUP BY dr.doc_id
   ```
2. To find revision with latest date among all chosen document's revisions which was transmitted to user XYZ:

   ```
   SELECT dr.doc_id, dr.id, MAX(tr.shippingtimestamp)
     FROM transmittals2revisions t2r, transmittals tr, docrevisions dr
     WHERE t2r.transmittal_id = tr.id
       AND dr.id = t2r.revisions_id
     GROUP BY dr.doc_id
   ```

Hence, we can combine them into one query:

```
     SELECT d.id doc_id, 
            rl.id last_revision_id, 
            rlt.id last_trans_revision_id, 
            rlt.transmittalnr,
            rlt.userto_id,
            rlt.rsn
      FROM documents d,
      (
       SELECT dr.doc_id, dr.id, MAX(dr.revisiondate)
         FROM docrevisions dr
         GROUP BY dr.doc_id
      ) rl,
      (
       SELECT dr.doc_id, dr.id, 
              tr.transmittalnr, tr.userto_id,
              t2r.rsn,
              MAX(tr.shippingtimestamp)
         FROM transmittals2revisions t2r, 
              transmittals tr, 
              docrevisions dr
         WHERE t2r.transmittal_id = tr.id
           AND dr.id = t2r.revisions_id
           AND tr.userfrom_id = 1
         GROUP BY dr.doc_id
      ) rlt
      where d.id = rl.doc_id 
        AND d.id = rlt.doc_id;
```

where *d.id* - document, *rl.id* - last revision, *rlt.id* - last transmitted revision.
As I understand *shippingtimestamp* - the time of transmission.

Comment: Although there are two small issues with your solution, it has helped me to find what I need, so thank you! Please see below for the issues and for the final solution of my problem.